Research collaboration outside of university for first 9 months as international student in United States
Is (unpaid) research collaboration outside of universities not permitted for F1 students in the United States for the first 9 months? After 9 months, if a student wants to collaborate, does it require CPT?

Not enough details on what you intend here. Your university international office can better inform you. If this collaboration is outside of your university program it likely will interfere with you making the necessary progress as a full time student in a PhD program.

These should be questions you ask your Designated School Official. Unpaid outside "collaborations" (which, given how you phrased it, sounds like "unpaid internship" to me) could actually be considered a form of employment and a violation of your visa.

F-1 students typically cannot engage in off-campus employment during their first academic year (9 months) in the U.S. This includes unpaid research collaborations. The restriction aims to help students focus on studies and maintain visa status. After the first academic year, F-1 students may become eligible for:

Curricular Practical Training (CPT)
Optional Practical Training (OPT)
Whether a research collaboration requires CPT depends on factors such as how it relates to the student's course of study or whether it's considered part of the curriculum.

Source: U.S. Immigration and Customs Enforcement (ICE). "Student and Exchange Visitor Program: Employment." https://www.ice.gov/sevis/employment
